# elasticsearch 5.0 return unique values

Tags: elasticsearch, unique

Having fields like:

- color:red
- color:green
- color:yellow
- color:red

i want the result to have

`[red,green,yellow]`

returning unique values that exist in mi index in that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the cardinality keyword:

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "distinct_colors": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "color"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The cardinality aggregation is an excellent tool, but OP asked for the values themselves. The cardinality aggregation returns an estimate of the number of unique values. The question is marked as a duplicate and the existing question has the correct answer.